# Add/Remove layout containing multiple widgets pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlayout

I'm trying to make a gui that allows the addition/removal of multiple QtWidgets. The user selects a file and has the option off adding a comment in the lineedit next to it. A quick search on this site has so far given me the following code which allows me to add rows widgets.

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class Additional(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Additional, self).__init__()

        self.addButton     = QtWidgets.QPushButton('  +   ')
        self.delButton     = QtWidgets.QPushButton('  -   ')
        self.acceptButton  = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Accept')
        self.cancelButton  = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel')

        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.addWidget)
        self.delButton.clicked.connect(self.delWidget)
        self.acceptButton.clicked.connect(self.acceptValues)
        self.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.cancel)

        self.scrollLayout  = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()

        self.scrollWidget  = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)

        self.scrollArea    = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)

        self.button_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout    = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.button_layout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        self.button_layout.addWidget(self.delButton)
        self.button_layout.addWidget(self.acceptButton)
        self.button_layout.addWidget(self.cancelButton)

        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.button_layout)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.resize(800, 200)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.show()

    def addWidget(self):
        self.scrollLayout.addRow(AddRow())

    def delWidget(self):
        # Would this call another class to remove the row? If so, how?
        pass

    def acceptValues(self):
        # Would I count the widgets in the 'scroll' area and get the data from that?
        pass

    def cancel(self):
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit()
        # BTW, is this the right way to close the window/instance?



class AddRow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__( self, parent=None):
        super(AddRow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button   = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Select file')
        self.label    = QtWidgets.QLabel('Selection will go here')
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineedit.setPlaceholderText("Rename (optional)...")
        # Would I add the button callback here?


        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)

        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
myApp = Additional()
app.exec_()
```

I'm trying to figure out:

- How to delete the last row that's been added.
- How to assign the action to the button (this be done in the 'AddRow' 
  class like`self.buttton.clicked.callback(self.selectfile)`
- How to collect the data from the rows (ie, after 'accept' has been
  clicked)

Any ideas would be welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before pointing to the solution, I'm just going to change the name of the AddRow class to RowWidget because a class should not indicate action.

```
class RowWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__( self, parent=None):
        super(RowWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        ...
```

### How to delete the last row that's been added ?

Since you are using QFormLayout and assuming that you are using a version PyQt5>=5.8 you can use the [removeRow()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#removeRow) method:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def delWidget(self):
    if self.scrollLayout.rowCount() > 0:
        self.scrollLayout.removeRow(self.scrollLayout.rowCount()-1)
```

### How to assign the action to the button (this be done in the 'AddRow' class likeself.buttton.clicked.callback(self.selectfile)?

Each part of your application must be independent so the slot that you select the file must be part only of RowWidget, and RowWidget must have a method that returns that value:

```
class RowWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__( self, parent=None):
        super(RowWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button   = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Select file')
        self.label    = QtWidgets.QLabel('Selection will go here')
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineedit.setPlaceholderText("Rename (optional)...")

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_select_file)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_select_file(self):
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File")
        if filename:
            self.lineedit.setText(filename)

    def get_filename(self):
        return self.lineedit.text()
```

### How to collect the data from the rows (ie, after 'accept' has been clicked)?

The widgets attached to a layout are children of the widget where the layout has been added, that widget can be obtained through [parentWidget()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#parentWidget), having that parent we can obtain their children through [findChildren()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren):

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def acceptValues(self):
    l_values = []
    for w in self.scrollLayout.parentWidget().findChildren(RowWidget):
        l_values.append(w.get_filename())
    print(l_values)
```

The previous method may fail if the `parentWidget()` has other children that belong to `RowWidget`.

Another option, and that does not fail is to iterate through the `QLayoutItem`s:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def acceptValues(self):
    l_values = []
    for i in range(self.scrollLayout.rowCount()):
        layout_item = self.scrollLayout.itemAt(i)
        if isinstance(layout_item.widget(), RowWidget):
            l_values.append(layout_item.widget().get_filename())
    print(l_values)
```

Comment: @JamesPorter If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct and give it an upvote, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: I forgot to ask, in the event of removeRow() not being available, was there an alternative?

Comment: @JamesPorter What version of PyQt5 do you have?

Comment: @ eyllanesc, according to what's built into maya, running `print PySide2.__version__` returns "2.0.0~alpha0"

Comment: @JamesPorter mmm, pyqt5 or pyside2 ?, although both are bindings of Qt5 can have different implementations and behaviors, on the other hand the current version of PySide2 is 5.11.2, version 2.0 is deprecated, later I will publish an alternative.

Comment: PySide2. My example code was form Qt5. I've two options, find an alternative for that version of pyside2 or try and get my pyside2 bindings in maya updated. Which sounds like a pain in the backside!!!

Comment: @JamesPorter Although you think that PyQt5 and PySide2 are similar, the truth is that in certain parts they are different, so if you want help in pyside2 show an example with pyside2. As I say when I have time I will try to show an alternative for your version of pyside2.